# How to hide a div tag using php

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement

In the below code, I'm trying to hide the div if `($settings['type'] != 11)`. The internal if statements work well, but if `($settings['type'] = 11)` div is visible and it works well. But, incase if `($settings['type'] != 11)` then div should be hidden. But it is displayed.

```
  <?php
    if ($settings['type'] = 11) {
    ?>
           <div id="hr" >
          <br>
              <?php $str1="abc";
               if (strcmp ( $str1 ,  "abc" )==0):?> 
               Test
               <center>
               Contact
               </center>
              <?php elseif (strcmp ( $str1 ,  "bca" )==0):?> 
              Test else<center>
              Contact</center>
        </div>
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php }?>
```

How can I debug this? What can be causing this problem.

Comment: There is a difference between `=` and `==`!

Comment: Just to explain the answers below, using a single "=" sets the variable value. Using "==" means "is equal to". (Using "===" means "is equal to, and the same type".)
So, `$x = 1` will return `1` and set `$x` to `1`.
`$x == 1` will return `true` if `$x` is (truthy) equal to `1`.
`$x === 1` will return `true` if `$x` is `1`, but `false` if `$x` is `"1"` (as that is a string, not an integer).

Comment: Also note that this will not 'HIDE' your div. The Div will just never exist on the page. Don't confuse "not rendering a certain part" with "CSS's `display: none` (hidden)". Semantics i guess, but not useless to keep the difference in mind and pick your words accordingly.

Comment: How can I debug such issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Condition should be like this :

```
<?php
    if ($settings['type'] == '11') {
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this to.

```
if ($settings['type'] = 11)
```

this

```
if ($settings['type'] == 11)
```

Use `==` or `===` for comparison operators.`=` is the assignment operator.

Check the [DOCUMENTATION](https://www.php.net/ternary) for more